# filling legend R shading

Tags: r, highcharts, legend

```
plot(1:4, 1:4, type="n", xaxt="n", xlab="", yaxt="n", ylab="")
polygon(c(2,4,2), c(1,3,3), col="gray")
polygon(c(3,3,1), c(1,3,2), col="red", density=10)
legend("topleft", legend=c("A", "B", "AB"), fill=c("gray", "red", "gray"),
       density=c(NA, 10, NA), bty="n",border=c("black", "red", "black")) 
legend("topleft", legend=c("A", "B", "AB"), fill=c("gray", "red", "red"),
       density=c(NA, 10, 10), bty="n", border=c("black", "red", "black"))
```

This doesn't work. 
I wanted to draw in the legend a square with the colour that I wanted. 
`border=c("black", "red", "black"))` in theory this sentence allows me change that color.

> Error in legend("topright", legend = c("TBR", "TBF", "Criterion",
>   "Hit"),  :    argument 8 matches multiple formal arguments

Comment: What exactly does not work? If I run the code here (without the **, of course), it does not throw an error and looks allright.

Comment: The legend doesn't appear and if I remove border=c("black", "red", "black")) it works

Comment: Which platform, Rstudio version, R version are you using? The code including `border=` works fine here, legend shows up as intended. (Win7, latest R + Rstudio).

Comment: This doesn't looks like connected to Highcharts. Is there a problem with the Highcharts library?

Comment: You want to plot two legends on top of each other to end up with the 3rd box being a red box, filled with grey and red stripes, do I get that right? This works perfectly for me on opensuse15. Please check your minimum working exampe! Btw.: removing 'border=c("black", "red", "black"))', you removed the closing bracket at the end of the statement.